# MVC Music Store tutorial, all information reset itself after weeks of it working fine. Why is this?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I have worked through the [MVC Music Store](http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/) tutorials.

All the Albums, Artists, Genres and Album Artwork I added in the Admin area of the site has deleted itself and reset itself to its original settings, All the Albums, Artists, Genres and Album Artwork has changed to everything from the sample data list they give you, why is this?

I clicked undo all pending changes to see if it would go back to how it was but it didn't.

I have even tried getting the specific version from this morning, this didn't fix the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a wild guess but maybe you changed something in the model and Entity Framework has dropped the database and seeded everything with some default values?

Check in your Global.asax if did this:

```
Database.SetInitializer<YourContext>(new SomeInitializer);
```

Comment: Yeah thats whats happened, is there a way that I can roll back?

Comment: Maybe SQL server did a back up from the Database but otherwise you can't recover it.